# Digital signing jar file

Tags: java, jar, digital-signature

I'm making a new plugin for jdownloader an open source download manager. I've made the plugin in eclipse. I tried exporting the package as a jar file and placing it in the directory for plugins however jdownloader doesn't recognise the new plugin.

I have noticed all other jdownloader plugins from other authors are in jar archive files including a manifest with java classes and their corresponding SHA1-Digest values. Does this mean i need my jar digitally signed? If so, how.

How can you find out if a digitally signed jar is necessary to work with a particular application? I have no intention of making it publicly available as it would be of no use to anyone but me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like this: http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/signing_eclipse_plugins/

More general article about JAR signing http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/85application/jar/sign.html